# Achievements system like in Starcraft2

Tags: frame-buffer, achievements, starcraft-2, replays

I am playing Starcraft2 and I am fascinated of how it is engineered. So lets say you played a 1v1 ranked game and you pumped 10 marines in the first 320 seconds. You'll get an achievement for that. I was wondering how is the achievements system designed underneath? Yes it analyzes the replay file which is frame based, but how?
There are 1000 achievements now.

Comment: I doubt it analyzes the replay file. It probably just keeps track of achievements on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achievement systems are actually pretty simple.

They can be built in any number of ways, but they revolve around two things:

1. Statistics tracking

   - Every time a thing happens, a notification (event, a method call, or other notification type) is sent off to the statistics tracking object saying "this thing happened." e.g. When you build a marine, the statistics tracker adds 1 to the `numMarinesBuilt` value
   - Singleton or a static class is sufficient for a single player game, for multiplayer you'd need an instance per player
2. Statistics comparison

   - Then the altered statistic is compared against a threshold value of some kind, and if all checks pass, the achievement is awarded. e.g. `if(Achievements.marines320.isNotAwarded() && numMarinesBuilt > 10 && curGameTime < 320) { //award achievement }`

Both happen in the same method, usually.  Some achievements like "win a game never having destroyed an outpost" have the logic split up: *destroying* an outpost sets a flag to true ("we did this thing at least once"), then when the game *ends* and the win logic is checked, the statistics comparison is made to check to see that that flag is still false ("if we did *not* do the thing: achievement").

Receiving the achievement would then fire off its own notificaiton to a central handler that would result in the popup saying "Yay you did Thing!" with a picture icon and some text on a GUI object background.  If using SteamworksAPI (or similar) you'd also inform the API of the achievement as well.

Comment: This is a good explanation of how you'd hardcode something like this, but I think the OP would do better with an explanation of how it's handled from a non-developer standpoint. Keep in mind that the achievement system is handled by game designers, not programmers, in most cases, so most achievement systems would have to be designed as a tool that could be used by game designers (i.e. non programmers) to setup the conditions for an achievement.

Comment: Do you mean in terms of "what makes a good statistic?" And "what level of a statistic makes a good achievement?" That gets very opinion based very quickly, which is considered off-topic.

Comment: I think they mean that the code/achievement are not hardcoded but in some sort of language. To develop that there would be in two parts, statistics would be hardcoded. Updated statistics trigger some kind of bytecode like interpreter. This could happen in a separate thread. http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/bytecode.html

Comment: Its possible.  I didn't get that from the asker's post, however.

Comment: Me neither, that's why I added it as comment not a more elaborate answer. Upvoted your answer as it answers the posted question.

Comment: Fair enough.  The question is just vague enough that your comment is applicable.  Trying to turn it into a complete answer though (kind of becomes an answer to "how do I program an interpreter?") isn't anything *I* could do (and possibly neither you, but I know that I failed that particular class in college ;).

Comment: You wouldn't hardcode the statistics, you'd hardcode events "unit died," "unit created," "timer elapsed," "unit attacked," etc...

Then you'd have a script interpreter (or perhaps a flow chart) that would tie events to a particular set of events for an achievement:

ACHIEVEMENT MAKE_MARINES:
CONDITION=UNIT.CREATE.TYPE="MARINE" AND TIMER.LESSTHAN="320"
TEXT="More where that came from"

Comment: Well, you'd have to encode some numbering as well, that achieve would trigger on the first marine built prior to 320 seconds, i.e. there's no "count:10" anywhere.  Besides the point, though.  I was more making reference to the "Then you'd have a script interpreter" part being rather more complicated than most people are willing to attempt.